# why $w(B^*AB)\leq \|B\|^2w(A)?$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space, $\mathcal{L}(E)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $E$. If $S\in \mathcal{L}(E)$, the numerical radius of $S$ is defined us
$$w(ََS) = \sup_{\|u\|= 1}|\langle Su, u\rangle |.$$

> For $A,B\in \mathcal{L}(E)$, why
>   $$w(B^*AB)\leq \|B\|^2w(A)?$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $u$ with norm $1$, we have

$$|\langle B^*ABu,u\rangle|=|\langle ABu,Bu\rangle| = \|Bu\|^2\,\left| \left\langle A(\frac{Bu}{||Bu||}), \frac{Bu}{||Bu||}\right\rangle \right| \leq ||B||^2 \,w(A)$$

Taking the supremum over all such $u$ with norm $1$ gives us $w(B^*AB) \leq  ||B||^2 w(A)$ as required

Answer (score 2):

You can estimate
$$
w(B^\ast AB) = \sup_{\|u\| = 1} |\langle B^\ast A B u, u\rangle| = 
\sup_{\|u\| = 1} |\langle A B u, Bu\rangle| \le 
\sup_{\|v\| \le \|B\|} |\langle A v, v\rangle| = 
\sup_{\|v\| \le 1} \|B\|^2 |\langle A v, v\rangle| \, .
$$